# getDate Function python

Tags: python, function, nameerror

Having trouble trying to get the date. All the libraries are installed but once I try and run the `print(getDate())` function I get a error: `NameError: name 'calender' is not defined`. The code is below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
my_date = datetime.datetime.today()
weekday = calender.day_name[my_date.weekday()] 
monthNum = now.month
dayNum = now.day

#List of months
month_names = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 
'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

#List of ordinal numbers
ordinalNumbers = ['1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th', '5th', '6th', '7th', '8th', '9th', '10th', 
'11th', '12th', '13th', '14th', '15th', '16th', '17th', '18th', '19th', '20th', '21st', 
'22nd', '23rd', '24th', '25th', '26th', '27th', '28th', '29th', '30th', '31st']

return 'Today is '+weekday+' '+ month_names[monthNum - 1]+' the '+ ordinalNumbers[dayNum - 
1]+'. '
```

Comment: Have you imported the required modules?

Comment: `weekday = calender.day_name[my_date.weekday()] ` has spelling mistake. It should be `weekday = calendar.day_name[my_date.weekday()] `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one misspelling. Import and use `calendar` instead of `calender`.

Comment: Thanks brother! Don't know how i missed that.

Answer (score 0):

it works fine you just have a spelling mistake the module name is calendar not calender

Comment: Thank you! Totally missed that.